# NEAR Protocol Rust contracts - what's the difference between near-sdk-rs data structures and std ones?

Tags: rust, blockchain, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

In Rust we have many data structures available in the standard library. NEAR Protocol has some optimized data structures in `near-api-rs`, but what are the main differences?

Answer (score 3):

[Evgeny Kuzyakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12055304/evgeny-kuzyakov) (a [Near protocol engineer](https://near.org/team/)) answered in Discord:

If you talking about LookupMap vs HashMap then the difference is LookupMap is stored in the trie, while HashMap is stored in memory.

When a method on a contract is called, the contract reads and deserializes the main struct from the storage trie. If it contains a HashMap then all records of this map will be read and deserialized. If it contains a LookupMap then only the key_prefix will be read and deserialized, so it's cheaper from gas perspective. But every time you access a key/value from a LookupMap you have to read and deserialize it from the trie.